# How to add a column to Dataset without converting from a DataFrame and accessing it?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am aware of method to add a new column to a Spark DataSet using `.withColumn()` and a `UDF`, which returns a DataFrame. I am also aware that, we can convert the resulting DataFrame to a DataSet.

My questions are:

1. How does DataSet's type safety comes into play here, if we are still following traditional DF approach (i.e passing column names as a string for UDF's input)
2. Is there an "Object Oriented Way" of accessing columns(without passing column names as a string) like we used to do with RDD, for appending a new  column.
3. How to access the new column in normal operations like map, filter etc?

For example:

```
    scala> case class Temp(a : Int, b : String)    //creating case class
    scala> val df = Seq((1,"1str"),(2,"2str),(3,"3str")).toDS    // creating DS
    scala> val appendUDF = udf( (b : String) => b + "ing")      // sample UDF

    scala> df.withColumn("c",df("b"))   // adding a new column
    res5: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: int, b: string ... 1 more field]

    scala> res5.as[Temp]   // converting to DS
    res6: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Temp] = [a: int, b: string ... 1 more field]

    scala> res6.map( x =>x.  
    // list of autosuggestion :
    a   canEqual   equals     productArity     productIterator   toString   
    b   copy       hashCode   productElement   productPrefix
```

the new column `c`, that i have added using `.withColumn()` is not accessible, Because column `c` is not in the case class `Temp` (it contains only `a` & `b`) at the instant when it is converted to DS using `res5.as[Temp]`.

How to access column `c`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the type-safe world of `Dataset`s you'd map an structure into another.

That is, for each transformation, we need schema representations of the data (as it is needed for RDDs). To access 'c' above, we need to create a new schema that provides access to it.

```
case class A(a:String)
case class BC(b:String, c:String)
val f:A => BC = a=> BC(a.a,"c") // Transforms an A into a BC

val data = (1 to 10).map(i => A(i.toString))
val dsa = spark.createDataset(data)
// dsa: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[A] = [a: string]

val dsb = dsa.map(f)
//dsb: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[BC] = [b: string, c: string]
```

Comment: Is there any other way to add a column without passing strings?

Comment: @vdep `String` is just an example to follow the vein of the question.

Comment: No, i meant that can we do it without passing the column name `b` as a string here : `df.withColumn("c",df("b"))`

Comment: @vdep Can you imagine an API for this? How would *you* do it if you were in charge of the API for Datasets? I'm curious why you're so in need to have it different.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski For example, If i can use it like : `df.withColumn("c",df.b)` instead of `df.withColumn("c",df("b"))` , I will be able to catch errors like misspelled column name or accessing a non existing columns etc at the compiling stage itself , rather than getting "column not found exception" at the runtime. This is just my humble thought/opinion and is not a major need or requirement.

Comment: So I think @maasg's answer with case classes reflects my sentiments very well (and I pass to offer a better solution).

Answer (score 4):

Just to add to @maasg's excellent answer...

> How does DataSet's type safety comes into play here, if we are still following traditional DF approach (i.e passing column names as a string for UDF's input)

Let me answer this with another question "Who is we in 'we are still following...'"? If you think me, I disagree and only use DataFrames when I'm too lazy to create a case class to describe the data set to work with.

My answer to UDFs is to stay away from UDFs unless they are very simple and there is nothing Spark Optimizer could optimize. Yes, I do believe UDFs are far too easy to define and use that I myself got carried away far too many times to (over)use them. There are around 239 functions available in Spark SQL 2.0 that you could think hard(er) to think of a solution without UDFs but standard functions.

```
scala> spark.version
res0: String = 2.1.0-SNAPSHOT

scala> spark.catalog.listFunctions.count
res1: Long = 240
```

(240 above is because I registered one UDF).

You should always use standard functions since they can be optimized. Spark can control what you're doing and hence optimize your queries.

You should also use Datasets (not `Dataset[Row]` i.e. `DataFrame`) because they gives you access to type-safe access to fields.

(Yet some of the Dataset "goodies" can't be optimized either since Dataset programming is all about Scala custom code that Spark can't optimize as much as DataFrame-based code).

> Is there an "Object Oriented Way" of accessing columns(without passing column names as a string) like we used to do with RDD, for appending a new column.

Yes. Of course. Use case classes to define your schema of Datasets and use the field(s). Both to access and add (that's what @maasg responded to nicely so I'm not gonna repeat his words here).

> How to access the new column in normal operations like map, filter etc?

Easy...again. Use the case class that describes (the schema of) your data sets. How do you add a new "something" to an existing object? You can't unless it *somehow* has accepted to have a new column, doesn't it?

In ""Object Oriented Way" of accessing columns or appending a new column." if your column is an attribute of a case class, you can't say "This is a class that describes the data and at the same time say this is a class that may have a new attribute". It's not possible in OOP/FP, is it?

That's why adding a new column boils down to use another case class or use `withColumn`. What's wrong with that? I think there is...simply...nothing wrong with that.