# How use Window aggrgates on strongly typed Spark Datasets?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

I'm slowely trying to adapt to the new (strongly typed) `Dataset[U]` from `Spark 2.x`, but struggling to maintain the type info when using `Window` functions.

```
case class Measurement(nb:Long,x:Double)
```

`ds` being a `Dataset[Measurement]`, I would like to do something like

```
ds.map{m => (m,sum($"x").over(Window.orderBy($"nb"))}
```

But this will not work (as it gives my a `Dataset[(Measurement,Column)]`) instead of `Dataset[(Measurement,Double)]`

Using `withColumn`  gives me a `Dataset[Row]`, so I'm loosing the type info:

```
ds.withColumn("cumsum",sum($"x").over(Window.orderBy($"nb")))
```

So, is there a better way to use `Window` functions on strongly typed `Datasets`?

Comment: `ds.withColumn("cumsum",sum($"x").over(Window.orderBy($"nb")))` should have you `Dataset[(Measurement,Double)]` row wise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you adding a new column to your dataset, I guess there is no choices but using the `dataframe.as[New Type]` method

---

More information can be found here [How to add a column to Dataset without converting from a DataFrame and accessing it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40608311/how-to-add-a-column-to-dataset-without-converting-from-a-dataframe-and-accessing)

More information on Window functions can be found on this blog article [Window Functions in Spark SQL by Databricks](https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `as[U]` method to convert a `Dataframe` (or `Dataset[Row]`) to a `Dataset[U]`

For you special case :

```
ds.withColumn("cumsum",sum($"x").over(Window.orderBy($"nb"))).as[(Measurement,Column)]
```

Hope it helps

Comment: this is not strong typed